# How to do I send a message to a queue in Azure from an Azure function using python?

Tags: python, function, azure, queue

I am using an azure function that has a time trigger and I am trying to communication with a data base to return a list of dictionaries, I am trying to send each dictionary as a string (queue message) to a queue, I was going to do this with an output binder but could not figure out how to, so I am using the azure module. Problem is every message I send goes into a poison queue for some reason, and I cannot figure out why, here is a code snippet of what I have in my Azure function.

```
import os
import platform
import WorkWithDatabase
#import base64
from azure.storage.queue import QueueService
acc='...ACCOUNT NAME'
key='...KEY'

#Connect to QueueService 
queue_service = QueueService(account_name=acc, account_key=key)

#Pull missing data from the database,
#Call a function in another script to do this

missingList=WorkWithDatabase.ListRequests()

for item in missingList:
    queue_service.put_message('taskqueue', str(item))
```

Also Is there a way I can use the database as a resource in an azure function with python??

Answer (score 0):

For using these python packages, such as `pyodbc` or `pymssql` to connect Azure SQL Database, you need to install a custom version of Python on Azure Function, then to install `pip` for the custom verion of Python to install these package as you want.

So the steps as below.

1. Follow the document [Using a custom version of Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Using-a-custom-version-of-Python) to install a custom Python runtime in the path `site\tools` of Kudu via access the url `https://<your function name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`.
2. After custom python installation, to download a [`get-pip.py`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) file to the path `site\tool` of custom Python, then to install `pip` tool via command `python get-pip.py`.
3. Then, you can install these packages via `Scripts/pip.exe install <package-names>`.

Then, you can import these packages to write your code in your Azure Function on Azure portal.